# Redux dispatch is not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

I have an authorization middleware which executes  `if (action.type === 'AUTHENTICATE')`.
In this middleware I make a request to the server and if the response is okay I dispatch login action which updates `isLoggedIn = false` to `true`. But dispatch is not executing. Code is below

**authMiddleware.js**

```
import { authUser } from '../../api';
import { actions } from '../';

const authMiddleware = (store) => (next) => async (action) => {
  const { auth, login } = actions;
  if (action.type === auth.toString()) {
    const { success } = await authUser(action.payload);

    if (success) {

      // THIS LINE IS NOT EXECUTING 
      store.dispatch(login());
    } else next(action);
  }
};

export default authMiddleware;
```

**Component**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { actions } from '../../store';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.scss';

import Logo from '../../components/Logo';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import Input from '../../components/Input/Input';

const Login = () => {
  const inputs = useSelector((state) => state.inputs.login);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const mappedInputs = inputs.map((input) => (
    <Input {...input} key={input.id} />
  ));

  const handleRegisterClick = (e, page) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(actions.setPage(page));
    navigate('../registration', { replace: true });
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = e.target;
    
    dispatch(actions.auth({ email: email.value, password: password.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <aside className="aside">
        <Logo direction={'column'} />
      </aside>

      <main className="main">
        <div className="form__wrapper">
          <h2 className="form__title">Войти</h2>
          <form
            action="#"
            className="form"
            onSubmit={(e) => handleFormSubmit(e)}
          >
            {mappedInputs}
            <div className="help-wrapper">
              <a href="##" className="form__help-button">
                Забыли пароль?
              </a>
            </div>
            <Button text={'Войти'} type={'submit'} />
            <div className="form__link">
              Новый пользователь?{' '}
              <button onClick={(e) => handleRegisterClick(e, 'registration')}>
                Регистрация
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**reducer.js**

```
import initialState from './initialState';

const reducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  const POSSIBLE_VALUES = ['map', 'profile', 'login', 'registration'];

  if (type === 'SET_CURRENT_PAGE') {
    if (!POSSIBLE_VALUES.includes(payload)) return state;

    state.currentPage = payload;
    return { ...state };
  }
  if (type === 'LOGIN') {
    console.log('in login reducer')
    state.isLoggedIn = true;
    state.currentPage = 'map'; 
    return { ...state };
  }
  if (type === 'LOGOUT') {
    state.isLoggedIn = false;
    state.currentPage = 'login';
    return { ...state };
  }

  if (type === 'UPDATE_INPUT') {
    state.inputs.profile.map((inp) => {
      if (inp.name === payload.inputName) inp.value = payload.updatedValue;
      return inp;
    });
    return { ...state };
  }

  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

**actions.js**

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

export const setPage = createAction('SET_CURRENT_PAGE');
export const login = createAction('LOGIN');
export const logout = createAction('LOGOUT');
export const updateInput = createAction('UPDATE_INPUT');
export const auth = createAction('AUTHENTICATE');
```

Comment: If it's not executing, have you debugged why `success` is not truthy? Does the code execute up to this point correctly?

Comment: Yes, problem is not in if statement or in request. Code executes in that point